# add variable occurs between measurements LMM

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I am interested in adding a variable to a repeated measurements model, LMM (3 measurements of QOL). But unlike gender, for example, which does not change between measurements, the variables I want to add are dichotomous indicating whether a patient was hospitalized between the first and second measurement and likewise between the second and third measurement. The goal is to examine the effect of the first variable on the result of the second measurement and the effect The second variable on the third measurement.
A similar question when you want to add a continuous variable between the measurements indicating the length of hospitalization between the first and second measurement and between the second and third measurement.
I run the model in R using lmer function
The data is in long format.
I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Greetings! It would help to some degree to add your proposed model syntax. For example, its unclear what random effects you have, what family of regression you are using, or other important factors related to your LMM. Having this information would benefit answerers.